# Postgresql text searching, matching multiple words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, search

I don't know the name for this kind of search, but I see that it's getting pretty common.

Let's say I have records with the following file names:
'order_spec.rb', 'order.sass', 'orders_controller_spec.rb'

If I search with the following string 'oc' I would like the result to return 'orders_controller_spec.rb' due to match the o in orders and the c in controller.
If the string is 'os' then I'd like all 3 to match, '**o**rder_**s**pec.rb', '**o**rder.**s**ass', '**o**rders_controller_**s**pec.rb'.
If the string is 'oco' then I'd like '**o**rders_**co**ntroller_spec.rb'

What is the name for this kind of search and how would I go about getting this done in Postgresql?

Comment: I suggest to set up a full text search index http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch.html . It does exactly this and very very fast. Such a search engine like google or something else.

Answer (score 0):

This is a called a [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) search. One simple way to do it in Postgres is to use the [`LIKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html) operator (or several of the other options in those docs) and fill the spaces between your letters with a wildcard, which for `LIKE` is `%`. To match anything with an `o` followed by an `s` in the `words` column, that would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE words LIKE '%o%s%';
```

This is a relatively expensive search, but you can improve performance with a [`varchar_pattern_ops`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/indexes-opclass.html) or `text_pattern_ops` index to support faster pattern matching.

```
CREATE INDEX pattern_index ON table (words varchar_pattern_ops);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `'%o%s%'` will also catch stuff like `tom_russian` which is not correct

Comment: There's nothing indicating `tom_russian` wouldn't be a correct match. If you're thinking of Cmd-T-style file searching, it has weightings to prefer matches at the beginning of words, but still finds everything in the middle.